# I want to do some task in Background in swing

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am using swing timer to to load different pdf files in swing application
but I am facing a problem when ever I execute a program the screen remains blank for few seconds like 4 to 5 seconds and then the pdf file is rendered so during this time I want to show a message like please wait. Here is my sample code

```
          if (type[i].equalsIgnoreCase("PDF")) {
            int k = i;
            pdfTimer = new Timer(0, (ActionEvent e) -> {
                renderPDF(k);

            });
            pdfTimer.setDelay(1000*2);
            pdfTimer.start();
```

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker`.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Run rendering on [SwingWorker's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) background thread (`doInBackground`) method. That way, your GUI will remain responsive. From `done` method you can notify user that rendering is done. Keep in mind not to update any Swing `GUI` from `doInBackground` method since it runs outside of EDT.

P.S. Swing Timer is for repetitive tasks.

Comment: I also want to do repetitive task to render each and every page of pdf and only for the first time the screen remains blank

Answer (score 0):

*Just an alternative for* `SwingWorker`

By default show some message like *Loading...* and create a `Thread` to run in the background which loads the PDF and updates the window

```
class BackgroundThread implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {

      // the Swing call below must be queued onto the Swing event thread
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // OK To make Swing method calls here
            loadFile(args..);
            repaint();//Or something similar that fits your purpose
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can display a progress bar and compute the renderding on a second thread.

```
JLabel lblWait = new JLabel("Please wait...");
    lblWait .setBounds(116, 26, 113, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblWait );

    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    progressBar.setBounds(72, 66, 187, 16);
    contentPanel.add(progressBar);
    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        {
            final JButton btFin = new JButton("Cancel");
            btFin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    dispose();
                }
            });

            buttonPane.add(btFin);
        }
    }
     Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
              //You launch the thread with your progress bar as an argument
                maStructure.setaAfficher(new MgtSimulation(aAfficher, nombreSimulations).jouerSimulations(progressBar));
                maStructure.actualiserAffichage();
                dispose();
            }
          };
          t.start();
}
```

And you change your progress bar value in your method

```
public  BeanAffichage jouerSimulations(JProgressBar progressBar){
    //Variables

     for (int i = 0; i < nombreSimulations; i++) {           
        //Computing

         progressBar.setValue(Whatever you want);
    }



    return aAfficher;
}
```

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Just saying.

Comment: I always do stuff like that. Why is it an horrible idea ?

Comment: Because swing is not thread safe. And in your example, you are updating its components from some outer thread. What do you think why SwingWorker exists...

Comment: Im still a student and i didnt know anything about swing worker. Thanks for advice