# JProgressBar indeterminate mode, why thread required?

Tags: java, swing

I often use a jprogressbar in indeterminate mode to communicate an ongoing process to user.

```
JProgressBar systemProcess = new JProgressBar();  
systemProcess.setString(processName);
systemProcess.setIndeterminate(true); 
runSlowRequest();
systemProcess.setIndeterminate(false);
```

I always have to put the JProgressBar in a thread or it does not show.  I have used various versions of a thread, SwingWorker, SwingUtilities.invokelater, etc.
They all work, but when the thread ends the swing gui does a full repaint.

If I remove the thread the repaint doesn't occur but the progressbar doesn't work.

Why does a JProgressBar only work when in a thread?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to do some task in Background in swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871365/i-want-to-do-some-task-in-background-in-swing)

Comment: Keep in mind that you must not block the GUI thread with your long running task. As long as `runSlowRequest()` is running with the GUI thread, no GUI updates are visible.

Comment: Swing is single threaded and not thread safe - this means you must not execute long running or blocking operations within the Event Dispatching Thread and any updates to the ui  or any state the ui relies on must be done on the EDT. setIndeterminate may be triggering a repaint request automatically, but I wouldn’t rely on it. If I need the ui updated, I’d manually trigger it

Comment: Recommended reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: @Progman I think i knew the problem but reading it written like this made me wake up to it.